# Best practice for main.ts bootstrap call in Angular 17+ standalone configuration

Tags: angular, angular17

I have a question about the bootstrap call in `main.ts` in the Angular 17 standalone API configuration.  In particular: should providers/imports be added to the bootstrap call **in addition to** being imported into the standalone components, directives and pipes?

**Some context:**

I migrated a legacy Angular app to the new standalone API configuration.  I used the official [standalone migration guide](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration).  This schematic contains four migration steps, the third of which is:

> Run ng g @angular/core:standalone and select "Bootstrap the project
> using standalone APIs"

This step copies the providers/imports from the root - `NgModule` - module into the new bootstrap call in `main.ts`.  Mine now looks like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        importProvidersFrom(AppRoutingModule, BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, 
        MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, FormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule),
        provideAnimations(),
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
    ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can see that, for example, the Angular Material imports have been added to the `providers` array in the bootstrap call.  These have also imported individually in the components where they are needed, as is necessary in the standalone API setup.

So:

- why are they also imported in the bootstrap call?
- should I add any new imports I use in future to the bootstrap call as well?  i.e.: if in future I decide to use an Autocomplete, should I add the `MatAutocompleteModule` to the bootstrap call as well as in the component?

**Update**

As per the comments/answers below, the migration schematic adds more to the `bootstrapApplication` method than is necessary/desirable (to ensure a smooth migration).

I recommend refactoring it to the `app.config.ts` pattern.

After refactoring my setup is:

**main.ts**

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**app.config.ts**

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
};
```

The other imports (see `bootstrapApplication` in the original post) were either obsolete or should only be imported at component level.

Some further information: [Getting started with standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)

Comment: It's just doing what it can to maintain a working application but it can be improved. e.g. instead of AppRoutingModule there's now provideRouter.  Things like FormsModule should only be imported at component level imo. Also suggest generating a fresh project with the cli and matching the app.config.ts pattern. main.ts should be minimal

Comment: I see.  I did wonder if it is a 'belt and braces' step to ensure the migration process doesn't break anything, as you suggest.  I will try a fresh project and compare the difference.  Thank you  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me your target should look like this.

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        provideRouter(myRoutes)
        importProvidersFrom(ReactiveFormsModule),
        provideAnimations(),
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
    ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

- The `BrowserModule` is automaticially imported by the `bootstrapApplication` function.
- Routing should be provided by passing the routes to `provideRouter`
- Every Material import should be at a component level. Each standalone component should only import the material module it needs
- As improvements, you should look into replacing `provideAnimations` with `provideAnimationsAsync`, to lazy load the animation package
- FormsModule still requires to be loading, so it could be fine here.
- You could replace `withInterceptorsFromDi()` with `provideInterceptors` if you convert your interceptors to `InterceptorFn`

Comment: Doc is a bit scarce on it but I wrote an article : https://riegler.fr/blog/2023-10-04-animations-async (it's a feature I implemented)